# Sympy -- find point minimizing distance to three circumferences

Tags: python, sympy

I've been experimenting with various techniques for finding a point `(x,y)` which minimizes the summed distances from `(x,y)` to the circumferences of three circles.

The picture below shows an example arrangement of these circles and the positioning of `(x,y)` using the first three of four techniques.

[image: demo]

I'm now trying a fourth technique described in [this stackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366894/closest-point-to-3-or-more-circles). In short, I'd like to use `sympy` to calculate the 1st-order derivative of a loss function to find its minima/maxima and then calculate the 2nd-order derivative to isolate the minima.

This is the loss function:

$E(x,y) = \sum_i \big( (x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2 - r_i^2 \big)^2$

This is the 1st-order derivative:

$E'(x,y) = \sum_i \frac{y-y_i}{-x+x_i}$

Here is the code that attempts to solve the 1st-order derivative equation for `y` in terms of `x` and then substitute that in to solve for `x`:

```
x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')
x1, y1 = 0, 0
x2, y2 = 3, 0
x3, y3 = 2, 3

def fprime(x,y):
    return (y-y1)/(-x+x1) + (y-y2)/(-x+x2) + (y-y3)/(-x+x3)

sols = sympy.solve(fprime(x,y), y)
y = sols[0]
x_sols = sympy.solve(fprime(x,y), x)
y_sols = []
for x_sol in x_sols:
    y_sols.append(y.evalf(subs={x:x_sol}))

for x,y in zip(x_sols, y_sols):
    plt.scatter(float(x), float(y))
```

I don't believe I'm evaluating/solving these equations properly because the generated points are very wrong (see the below image)

[image]

To demonstrate that the gradient is not dependent on the radius of the circles:

```
In [2]: x,y = sympy.symbols('x y')

In [3]: xi, yi, ri = sympy.symbols('xi yi ri', constant=True)

In [4]: def f(x,y):
   ...:     return ((x-xi)**2 + (y-yi)**2 - ri**2)**2
   ...:
   ...:

In [5]: sympy.idiff(f(x,y), x, y)
Out[5]: (y - yi)/(-x + xi)
```

Comment: I did not calculate this, but I can't understand, how the gradient is not *r* dependend; there has to be a mistake in your calculations

Comment: @user8408080, please see the additional details at the end of the OP

Answer (score 1):

`idiff` does not compute the gradient. What you want is `sympy.vector.gradient`. I will go through this only for one pair (*x_i, y_i*):

```
import sympy
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, gradient

xi, yi, ri = sympy.symbols('xi yi ri', constant=True)
R = CoordSys3D('R')
f1 = ((R.x-xi)**2 + (R.y-yi)**2 - ri**2)**2
fprime = gradient(f1)
```

Which gives you

```
In [25]: fprime
Out[25]: ((4*R.x - 4*xi)*(-ri**2 + (R.x - xi)**2 + (R.y - yi)**2))*R.i + ((4*R.y - 4*yi)*(-ri**2 + (R.x - xi)**2 + (R.y - yi)**2))*R.j
```

This is a 2D vector field. We now want to find `R.x` and `R.y` so, that both components are zero. So first I solve the `R.i` component for zero:

```
sympy.solve(fprime.components[R.i], R.x)
```

yielding

```
[xi,
 xi - sqrt((-R.y + ri + yi)*(R.y + ri - yi)),
 xi + sqrt((-R.y + ri + yi)*(R.y + ri - yi))]
```

I just chose one solution from this, you can later verify if this is indeed a minimum. So now we need to plug this in the `R.j` component to get the equation for `R.y`:

```
eq = fprime.components[R.j].subs(R.x, xi - sympy.sqrt((-R.y + ri + yi)*(R.y + ri - yi)))
```

Solving this with

```
sympy.solve(eq3, R.y)
```

gives simply `y_i`, so we have our solution.

I hope this outlines what you have to do and that I didn't make any mistakes as I'm no sympy expert. I'm open for constructive criticism here.